# Most played this week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have 2 tables in my SQL:

- agames (*game_id* (must match *newentries id*), *ended* (1 or 0))
- newentries (*game_id*, *created* is where it should check date)

I wish to get the most popular game played this week, which is NOT ended (agames.ended = 1)

How? I tried this, without luck, hopefully someone can help me!

```
SELECT 
count(id) as a.rank, 
a.game_id 
FROM a.newentries, b.agames 
WHERE b.ended = 0 AND a.created = THIS_WEEK 
order by a.rank 
desc 
limit 1
```

Here is data set (and failed query attempt)

```
CREATE TABLE `newentries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `game_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `newentries` (`id`, `user`, `game_id`, `score`, `created`, `game_name`) VALUES
(3, 216, 46, 230, '2018-08-06 16:14:26', ''),
(4, 13436, 46, 0, '2018-08-07 12:14:18', ''),
(5, 13436, 46, 91, '2018-08-07 13:49:04', ''),
(6, 13436, 46, 97, '2018-08-07 15:10:10', ''),
(7, 13436, 46, 128, '2018-08-07 15:10:59', ''),
(8, 13436, 46, 75, '2018-08-07 15:48:44', ''),
(9, 13436, 46, 33, '2018-08-07 15:48:53', ''),
(10, 216, 46, 222, '2018-08-08 17:38:41', ''),
(11, 216, 46, 61, '2018-08-08 20:26:52', ''),
(12, 13440, 46, 56, '2018-08-08 20:39:48', ''),
(13, 13440, 46, 97, '2018-08-08 20:40:04', ''),
(14, 216, 46, 90, '2018-08-08 22:21:23', ''),
(15, 13440, 46, 264, '2018-08-09 12:01:09', ''),
(16, 13440, 46, 218, '2018-08-09 12:04:40', ''),
(17, 13440, 46, 746, '2018-08-09 12:05:54', ''),
(18, 13440, 46, 97, '2018-08-09 14:24:41', ''),
(19, 13440, 46, 91, '2018-08-09 14:25:07', ''),
(20, 13440, 46, 57, '2018-08-09 14:25:17', ''),
(21, 13440, 46, 56, '2018-08-09 14:25:27', ''),
(22, 13440, 46, 83, '2018-08-09 14:25:40', ''),
(23, 13440, 46, 395, '2018-08-09 14:25:54', ''),
(24, 13440, 46, 626, '2018-08-09 14:29:23', ''),
(25, 13440, 46, 165, '2018-08-09 17:56:36', ''),
(26, 13440, 46, 5, '2018-08-09 18:11:58', ''),
(27, 13440, 46, 163, '2018-08-09 18:16:32', ''),
(28, 13440, 46, 69, '2018-08-09 18:16:46', ''),
(29, 13440, 46, 54, '2018-08-10 10:31:20', ''),
(30, 13440, 46, 168, '2018-08-10 10:31:56', ''),
(31, 13440, 46, 242, '2018-08-10 10:32:56', 'candyjam'),
(32, 13440, 46, 165, '2018-08-10 11:14:36', 'sheepjump'),
(33, 13440, 47, 874, '2018-08-14 22:13:38', 'boatdash'),
(34, 13440, 21, 139, '2018-08-17 13:23:04', 'fruitblade'),
(35, 13440, 21, 120, '2018-08-17 13:23:25', 'fruitblade'),
(36, 13440, 51, 49, '2018-08-18 16:00:23', 'escapefromaztec'),
(37, 13436, 14, 150, '2018-08-20 10:55:39', ''),
(38, 13436, 14, 76, '2018-08-20 11:01:14', ''),
(39, 13436, 14, 870, '2018-08-20 11:07:21', ''),
(52, 13436, 14, 13, '2018-08-20 11:09:00', ''),
(53, 13436, 14, 13, '2018-08-20 11:09:00', ''),
(54, 13436, 14, 13, '2018-08-20 11:09:00', ''),
(55, 13436, 14, 13, '2018-08-20 11:09:00', '');

CREATE TABLE `agames` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prize_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `game_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ended` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `winner` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `gift_sent` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `site` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'bestplayerwins',
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Data dump for tabellen `agames`
--

INSERT INTO `agames` (`id`, `prize_id`, `game_id`, `start`, `end`, `ended`, `winner`, `created`, `gift_sent`, `site`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 7, 'fruitblade', '2018-08-24 10:31:08', '2018-08-25 08:31:08', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:31:08', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(2, 14, 'billthebowman', '2018-08-24 10:31:08', '2018-08-25 08:31:08', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:31:08', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(3, 11, 'boatdash', '2018-08-24 10:31:08', '2018-08-25 08:31:08', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:31:08', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(4, 3, 'bananajungle', '2018-08-24 10:31:08', '2018-08-25 08:31:08', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:31:08', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(5, 2, 'gravitykid', '2018-08-24 10:31:08', '2018-08-25 08:31:08', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:31:08', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(6, 13, 'candyjam', '2018-08-24 10:31:08', '2018-08-25 08:31:08', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:31:08', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(7, 19, 'mountainhop', '2018-08-24 10:37:36', '2018-08-31 08:37:36', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:37:36', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(8, 17, 'pinball', '2018-08-24 10:37:36', '2018-08-31 08:37:36', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:37:36', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(9, 23, 'fruitblade', '2018-08-24 10:37:36', '2018-08-31 08:37:36', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:37:36', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(10, 20, 'bananajungle', '2018-08-24 10:37:36', '2018-08-31 08:37:36', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:37:36', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(11, 24, 'candyjam', '2018-08-24 10:37:36', '2018-08-31 08:37:36', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:37:36', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(12, 26, 'sheepjump', '2018-08-24 10:37:36', '2018-08-31 08:37:36', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:37:36', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(13, 30, 'escapefromaztec', '2018-08-24 10:41:50', '2018-09-23 08:41:50', 0, 0, '2018-08-24 10:41:50', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 3),
(14, 4, 'pinball', '2018-08-25 00:00:01', '2018-08-25 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-25 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(15, 7, 'boatdash', '2018-08-25 00:00:01', '2018-08-25 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-25 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(16, 11, 'bananajungle', '2018-08-25 00:00:01', '2018-08-25 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-25 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(17, 2, 'candyjam', '2018-08-25 00:00:01', '2018-08-25 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-25 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(18, 5, 'escapefromaztec', '2018-08-25 00:00:01', '2018-08-25 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-25 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(19, 12, 'gravitykid', '2018-08-25 00:00:01', '2018-08-25 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-25 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(20, 10, 'billthebowman', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-08-26 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(21, 15, 'sheepjump', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-08-26 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(22, 14, 'pinball', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-08-26 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(23, 5, 'mountainhop', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-08-26 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(24, 12, 'gravitykid', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-08-26 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(25, 7, 'bananajungle', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-08-26 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(26, 21, 'mountainhop', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-09-01 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(27, 16, 'gravitykid', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-09-01 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(28, 25, 'escapefromaztec', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-09-01 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(29, 22, 'bananajungle', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-09-01 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(30, 24, 'fruitblade', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-09-01 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(31, 20, 'boatdash', '2018-08-26 00:00:01', '2018-09-01 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-26 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 2),
(32, 15, 'pinball', '2018-08-27 00:00:01', '2018-08-27 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-27 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(33, 5, 'mountainhop', '2018-08-27 00:00:01', '2018-08-27 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-27 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(34, 14, 'fruitblade', '2018-08-27 00:00:01', '2018-08-27 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-27 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(35, 3, 'boatdash', '2018-08-27 00:00:01', '2018-08-27 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-27 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(36, 2, 'candyjam', '2018-08-27 00:00:01', '2018-08-27 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-27 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1),
(37, 9, 'gravitykid', '2018-08-27 00:00:01', '2018-08-27 22:00:01', 0, 0, '2018-08-27 00:00:01', 0, 'bestplayerwins', 1);

SELECT count(id) as a.rank, a.game_id 
FROM a.newentries ne
JOIN b.agames ag ON ne.game_id = ag.game_id
WHERE b.ended = 0 AND a.created BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY a.rank DESC LIMIT 1
```

and SQLFIddle of same:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/190069/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try

```
SELECT count(ne.id) as rank, ne.game_id 
FROM newentries ne
JOIN agames ag ON ne.game_id = ag.game_id
WHERE ag.ended = 0 AND ag.created BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you want to get the exact time instead of just the day, use `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`.

There isn't any `LAST_WEEK` expression in MySQL. You've probably gotten confused by seeing something like this:

```
SELECT Id, SomeField, SomeOtherField,
   SUM(IF(SomeDate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE(), 1, 0) AS THIS_WEEK,
   SUM(IF(SomeDate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK, 1, 0) AS LAST_WEEK
FROM SomeTable
```

This example would add the field names `THIS_WEEK` and `LAST_WEEK` to the resultset, containing the number of dates occurring this week and last week, respectively. The `AS` keyword is used to rename a field or a calculation in the resultset.

Edit: Sorry, getting late. Your other problem is that `SELECT count(id) as a.rank` will give you a syntax error. `AS` is used to rename the column header in the result, and you can't have periods in column headers. You're confusing this with the idea of specifying which server (a or b) the data is coming from.

Edit2: After seeing your SQLfiddle, `id` is indeed ambiguous, because you have it as the name in two different tables. You have to specify which one you want to select. I've edited the query above.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.rank, a.game_id FROM a.newentries ne JOIN b.agames ag ON ne.game_id = ag.game_' at line 1

Comment: @JesperJebberKampmann Try it now. You can't put a period in an `AS` value. As it sits now, the count of the id will have the column header `rank` in your result.

Comment: Hello, allright, sorry, im quite new for this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/190069/2 it says "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous" - what means? Can you please check in sqlfiddle?

Comment: SELECT count(a.id) as rank, a.game_id FROM newentries a JOIN agames b ON a.game_id = b.id WHERE b.ended = 0 AND a.created BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 1 seems to work! Thanks!!

Comment: @JesperJebberKampmann You beat me to it. The problem is with your data. If you look, your game_id in the first table is numbers, and game_id in agames has names like billthebowman, fruitblade, etc. So none of the joins will ever match up. Of course you join newentries.game_id with agames.id, since the game id in newentries is the id of the agames table. You might want to read up on "foreign keys."

Answer (score -1):

please try

```
SELECT count(id) as a.rank, a.game_id 
FROM a.newentries, b.agames 
WHERE b.ended = 0 AND YEARWEEK(a.created, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
order by a.rank desc limit 1
```

Use can use a specific mode like 0 -> sunday, 1 -> monday.....

Comment: Hello. Thanks so much. I think a.rank, a.game_id doesn't work properly. It's newer SQL. It makes error though. #1064 - Der er en fejl i SQL syntaksen nær '.rank, a.game_id 
FROM a.newentries, b.agames 
WHERE b.ended = 0 AND YEARWEEK(' på linje 1

Comment: what is structure of a.created??

Comment: It's datetime, like 2018-08-06 16:14:26